# jQuery global load page issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, load, global

I'm trying to create a global page, which would just change content instead of completely loading a new page.
When i try to call the loadPage function on the home.php page it just tells me the loadPage function isn't defined.
The problem is i think, that the function has to be re-created when the new content is loaded...

Global page code(HTML):

```
<!-- Please note: this is the part that loads the page, and displays the loading image -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/jQuery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/loadPage.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-loading.css">
<img class="loading-img" src="images/loading.gif">
<!-- End of note -->
<!doctype html>
<html>
</html>
```

Page loading code(JS):

```
//Copyright © 2016 Dynavio Cooperative
var currentPage = null;
$(document).ready(function()
{
    loadPage();
});
function loadPage(pageToLoad)
{
    $(".loading-img").removeAttr("style");
    if(typeof pageToLoad == "undefined")
    {
        if(currentPage == null)
        {
            $("html").load("pages/home.php", function()
            {
                $(".loading-img").css("display", "none");
            });
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $("html").load(pageToLoad, function()
        {
                $(".loading-img").css("display", "none");
        });
    }
}
```

home.php code(HTML):

```
<!-- Copyright © 2016 Dynavio Cooperative -->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="Dynavio">
<meta name="keywords" content="Dynavio,Cooperative,Administration">
<meta name="author" content="Dynavio Cooperative">
<title>Dynavio - Homepage</title>
<!-- Css styles -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/plugins/font-awesome-4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-main-global.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-fonts.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-navbar.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-slider.css">
<!-- End of Css styles -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/plugins/Slides-SlidesJS-3/source/jquery.slides.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/sliderInit.js"></script>
<!-- Javascript -->
</head>

<body>
<div class="navbar">
    <img src="images/logo.png" class="nav-logo">
    <ul class="nav-items">
        <li class="nav-item active">Homepage</li>
        <li class="nav-item">Products</li>
        <li class="nav-item">Company</li>
        <li class="nav-item">Research</li>
        <li class="nav-item">Contact</li>
        <li class="nav-item" onClick="loadpage(pages/login.php);">Login</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="intro-slider slider">
    <img src="images/example1.png">
    <img src="images/example2.png">
</div>
<div class="products">

</div>
</body>
<!-- Copyright © 2016 Dynavio Cooperative -->
```

Comment: The function should not need to be recreated. In your home.php file, are you calling the function before or after loading the JS file? If you call a function before the file is loaded then it will be undefined. Since that looks like the end of your html, I'd guess you'd have to load your JS above the function call.

Comment: Or, maybe the problem is that i'm actually re-linking the jquery file in home.php

Comment: Where are you calling actually calling the loadPage() function in Home.php? I don't see that code above. Also are you loading the jQuery file twice? I don't see that either.

Comment: i added my home.php code

Comment: I don't see any reference to js/loadPage.js in Homepage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was because function names are case-sensitive...

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your HTML. I know that that code was only a part of your code but doctype definition should always be in the first line.

Then, I can not see `<html>` tag open. I hope that it is on other part of your code.

Comment: You can try with another tag. I mean, you shoul not replace html tag but you can replace a child, body for example